# Call function on some objects in a vector containing different subclasses

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, vector, subclass

I have something like this:

```
class A {
    void add (A* a) {
        //add a to a vector<A*>
    }
    virtual void draw() = 0;
}

class B : public A {
    void tick() {}
    void draw() {}
}

class C : public A {
    void draw() {}
}
```

Now what I want to do is have a loop like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<vector.size(); i++) {
    vector[i]->tick();
}
```

Problem is that not all the elements in this vector will have the `tick()` method, but I still want to have them in the same vector because I also want to be able to loop through the vector and call `draw()` on all the elements. Is there some way to solve this? I'm considering having another vector but I'd rather not.

Comment: try a `dynamic_cast` to a type that implements the `tick` method? Alternatively, have a virtual implementation in the base class, which does nothing for the types that don't implement that method...

Comment: No, don't do either of those things. If you have a vector of objects where only some of those objects implement the functions that you want to invoke, then they should be in multiple collections. Create interfaces that _make sense_, and only derive from them when it _makes sense_.

Comment: this is very curious statement `vector[i]-->tick();`

Comment: Why not just give `A` a `virtual` `tick` method that does nothing. You can override it in `B`. (Also, don't make a `vector` of ordinary pointers. Either use a `vector` of smart pointers or use a `ptr_vector`, depending on what you want to happen when you copy the vector.)

Comment: Yes I actually thought about having one of the subclasses not deriving from the superclass at all, seems like that would make more sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a `vector` of widgets, but only some of those widgets have a dingbat, are they really all widgets?

In your case you have a `vector` of things that aren't the same.  This is your problem.  Sure, you could come up with some hacky, complex mechanism to put a battleship in a pencil cup.  Or you could do what I'd consider to be one of the Right Things:

1. Make sure everything you're putting in to the pencil cup is a pencil
2. Create someplace else to put the battleship.

Number 2 above is creating a seperate vector as you've already mentioned.  Number 1 might be as simply as providing a `virtual tick()` method with an empty (trivial) implementation on the base class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use visitor pattern at [this case](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/visitor/cpp/2). But it isn't best solution. You brake Liskov substitution principle. Rethink you hierarchy.